# Javascript calculator returns string instead of value

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript and I am currently trying to make a simple calculator. The problem I am having is that the calculator returns the actual equation(as a string) instead of the result value. [Here is a jsFIDDLE document](http://jsfiddle.net/3yJCd/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var score = "";

$("#nOne").click(function () {
    score += 1;
});
$("#nTwo").click(function () {
    score += 2;
});

$("#add").click(function () {
    score += "+";
});

$("#nEqual").click(function () {
    alert(score);
});
```

});

Also is there a preference in using `< input type="button">` or a `< div>` as a button or they are all the same in making a simple calculator?

Comment: good hint but still add button will mess things up. This is wrong logic to write calculator in my opinion

Comment: @raina77ow How would setting `score=0` solve the problem? There's `score += '+'` which converts `score` to a string again...

Comment: Web is full of "simple javascript calculator example"s, please just do some search to find them all (30 200 000 results), not my downvote though.

Comment: @Teemu Indeed, missed that `+` case. Now we're looking into `eval` direction, I suppose.

Comment: @raina77ow No worries, looks like nine other users have missed it too : ). Using `eval()` would probably be the simplest solution here, the question is, who dares to propose it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use eval() JavaScript function.

In the example, the buttons are not adding values, instead you are concatenating string values. After pressing #nOne, #add, #nTwo, you get "1+2" (string) in score, not 3 (number). eval() execute an expression (string) "converting" it to code. w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

```
$("#nEqual").click(function () {
    alert(eval(score));
});
```

although it would be ugly code!

Comment: If you can also explain, why `eval()` is needed, I'll upvote your answer ; ).

Comment: In the example, the buttons are not adding values, instead you are concatenating string values. After pressing `#nOne`, `#add`, `#nTwo`, you get "1+2" (string) in `score`, not 3 (number). 
eval() execute an expression (string) "converting" it to code.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Actually you should add the explanation to your answer, it'd serve future visitors better (and OP ofcourse)... +1 despite of referring w3schools : ).